# Input a search from the browser to an API get Request

Tags: javascript, html, api, dom

I am working on a homework project where I need to create a search, I need to take that search and plug it into an API request peram and have that API come back with a Gif URL relating to that search. I have the code for the search event listener, and I have the code for the API get request, where I am coming into trouble is getting them to work together. When I comment out one piece of code out the stand-alone works as intended.  I am trying to get the search URL to print to the console just to test to make sure I am receiving a URL. In the end, I will be appending it to the DOM but right now I am just focused on getting the URL back from the API.
Any input is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Giphy Party!</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>The Giphy Party!!!!!</h1>
      <h2>It is Party Time!!!!!</h2>
    </div>

    <form class="gform">
      <label for="search">
        <input id="searchInput" type="text" />
      </label>
      <button>Search Gif</button>
      <button>Remove Gifs</button>
    </form>

    <div class="container"><img id="img" src=""" alt="" /></div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


'''let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");
document.querySelector("form.gform").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(searchInput.value);
});


let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);


async function getGif() {
  const res = await axios.get("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search", {
    params: {
      api_key: "tGZu4GXgLVVp0VTINvh66xcmIfJBPqoP",
      q: searchInput,
    },
  });
  console.log(res.data.data[randomIndex].url);
}
getGif();'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling your getGif() function before the form was submitted. The event listener is not a synchronous event. To fix this, you can just move it into the event listener block:

```js
let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");
document.querySelector("form.gform").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(searchInput.value);
  getGif(); // move it up here. now it will work.
});


let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);


async function getGif() {
  const res = await axios.get("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search", {
    params: {
      api_key: "tGZu4GXgLVVp0VTINvh66xcmIfJBPqoP",
      q: searchInput,
    },
  });
  console.log(res.data.data[randomIndex].url);
}
```